# How to access data frame columns inside while loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, while-loop

I have created two data frames called `'Exmil_df'` and `'Schedule_df'. I need to iterate over all the elements inside the data frame.I am using the below code.

```
    i=0
    j=0
    Schedule_df['Allocation']=0
    while i < len(Exmil_df):
        while j < len(Schedule_df):
            while (Schedule_df[Schedule_df['Requirement']]>=Schedule_df[Schedule_df['Allocation']]):
                print('*')
```

But it's giving `KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([32000, 12000], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"`. Can't I access elements inside the loop in this way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: This works for 'for loop'. But in while loop its different